# jQuery Using .on() with .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make any TD cell with the string of "RW" have a class of red. I need to use .on because the grid has pagination and reloads new content. I need to also use each because there could be more than one TD cell containing the string.

```
 $("#json-table").on("tbody tr td"){
 if ($(this).text() == 'RW').each({
 $(this).addClass('red'))};
```

Comment: Suggest you read the jQuey documentation for [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to narrow down your set here, but without more information we can't say *where* to call it from.  Keeping in mind jQuery functions run on the entire collection, here's what you want:

```
$("#json-table tbody tr td").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'RW';
}).addClass('red');
```

...and you'll need to call that with your pagination code.

Edit: since it seems you're using datatables.net, a more complete example would be:

```
$('#json-table').bind('sort filter page', function () {
  $("tbody tr td", this).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'RW';
  }).addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: how do I call it with the pagination code? It could also be called via the column sort filters.

Comment: @ndesign11 - what are you using to do filtering and pagination?

Comment: class=DataTables_sort_icon & .fg-button

Comment: @ndesign11 - I assume your comment got corrupted but I recognize that class, if it is datatables.net, see the updated answer above.

Comment: Yeah Thanks!! that works for the column filtering but not the pagination buttons.   btw, the ID was massing the [']

Comment: @ndesign11 - how are you creating the pagination buttons? the same code can be a function and called both places, you want it to fire *after* pagination completes though (especially in AJAX), and not on click if there's a delay.

Comment: the pagination buttons are created using "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", thats why I was thinking on() might work because it needs to happen after the data is loaded in.

Comment: @ndesign11 - this *should* be firing after page, try adding an alert and seeing if it's simply firing before the data's in there...if that's the case you need to see how your data is loading, e.g. ajax and add the highlight call (.addClass(), etc.) to the end of that.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't concerned about the presence of other characters in the `td`, then you can more directly filter down to the correct cells by using the `:contains` selector:

```
$('#element_id').on('click', function() {
    $('#json-table td:contains("RW")').addClass('red');
});
```

Where `element_id` is the ID of the element you would like to assign the click event handler.

Comment: It's worth noting your use of `:contains` is not equivalent, it would match it anywhere in the cell's text, rather than doing an exact equality check.

Comment: You still wouldn't need an each there, you could chain that directly

Comment: @ElliotB. - here's an illustration of why `:contains()` is not equivalent and is overly broad: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JbwR3/1/ notice it matches cells that have text other than RW (given that particular string, it's probably file attributes, and you'd likely want an *exact* match)

Comment: @NickCraver Oh no worries, I completely get it. I'm not updating my answer because you've already provided the exact match `.filter()` example below. Why copy someone else? The OP should accept your answer.

Comment: @ElliotB. - I'm just suggesting you not leave an incorrect answer for others to find, it should include a caveat you're changing the matching pattern (a change which others finding this later may indeed want), that's all :)

Comment: @NickCraver I qualified my answer about 30 mins ago with: "If you aren't concerned about the presence of other characters in the td". I think that'd be sufficient. If you're concerned about incorrect answers, you should leave a note below with Sushanth's answer as well. He and I both assumed that the presence of other characters in the cell wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

**.on()**  and **.each()** are completely different . **.on()** `is used to attach an event` where as **.each()** `is used to iterate over objects or arrays.`

Try this

```
$("#json-table tbody tr td").each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
    if($this.text().indexOf('RW') > -1)){
        $this.addClass('red');
    }|
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) is used for handling events triggered by elements. Look at the documentation to learn the correct usage. Assuming you want to handle a click event, the syntax is shown below. You mention the event will be delegated, so your usage must match this signature.

```
$("#json-table").on('click', "tbody tr td", function() {
    if ( $(this).text() == 'RW') ) {
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }
});
```

Note, as is, your `.each` was chained on to the `if` statement, which is invalid JS. `this` already refers to the correct `<td>` element that you are targeting.